# Volume of revolution around $y$-axis

Tags: calculus

I would like to calculate the volume of revolution around $x$ and $y$ axis, of $D$ in the $xy$-plane, which has borders $x$-axis, $y$-axis, and the curve $4x-x^{2}$.

For the rotation around the $x$-axis, I just used the formula:
\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} 2 \pi \int_0^4 f(x)^2\,\mathrm dx=2 \pi \int_0^4 (4x-x^2)^2\,\mathrm dx=2 \pi \int_0^4(16x^2-8x^3+x^4)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=2 \pi \left[\frac{16x^3}3-2x^4+ \frac{x^5}{5} \right]_0^4=2 \pi \left[\frac{16 \cdot 64}3- 512 + \frac{1024}{5} \right]=2 \pi \cdot 1214,
\end{align*}
which I hope is correct.

But then I have to make the rotation around $y$-axis and I do not know how to find the inverse of $4x-x^2$. I am stuck here.

Comment: Hint: Try quadratic formula.

Comment: I don't understand how you mean. I thought about reverting the funtion $$4x-x^2$$ to make a rotation around y-axis. How do I use the quadratic formula for that?

Comment: It's probably easiest to use "shell" method, rather than "disk" method for the $y$-axis rotation.  Then you don't have to invert the function at all.

Comment: you shouldn't have the factor 2 in your first answer

Comment: @Dovendyr $y=4x-x^2 \iff -x^2+4x-y=0 \iff x=\frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{4^2-4y}}{-2}$. Then you know you only need to consider the $+$ sign above by considering the figure.

Comment: Ok, I get it. We do a quadratic formula to extract x, as the quadratic does. Sorry English AND math are not my mother tongue. Why only the plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a constant of 2 being multiplied by your first integral. Remember, when using the disk method, you're summing up the individual volumes of the "cylinders" as dx approaches 0. i.e.

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\sum_{i}^n\pi r^2 \Delta x \quad or \quad \int_a^b \pi r^2 dx  \quad where \ \ r=f(x)$$

With regards to integrating around the y-axis, it's much easier to use the shell method as you don't have to change your variable of integration to y.

$$\quad 2\pi \int_a^b x f(x) dx \qquad 2\pi \int_0^4 x(4x-x^2)dx=2\pi \int_0^4  (4x^2-x^3)dx=2\pi(\frac{4}{3} x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^4) \bigg|_0^4$$

Evaluate that and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you. I did that today and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

HINT...for the volume about the y axis, use concentric "tree-ring" elements: i.e evaluate $$2\pi\int_0^4x(4x-x^2)dx$$